# How can I have Tab titles in bootstrapvue as a dropdown

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm a newbie in vue.js and I've run into a challenge. The code below is for a tab component. How can one make the titles to be in a dropdown instead of being aligned horizontally all of them?

```
<div>
  <b-tabs content-class="mt-3">
    <b-tab title="First" active><p>I'm the first tab</p></b-tab>
    <b-tab title="Second"><p>I'm the second tab</p></b-tab>
    <b-tab title="Disabled" disabled><p>I'm a disabled tab!</p></b-tab>
  </b-tabs>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the default tab navigation using the `d-none` class in the `nav-class` prop.
This will add `display: none`, hiding the navigation.

You can then build your own navigation, in this case a dropdown using `<b-dropdown>`.
To do this you need to bind a data property to the `<b-tabs>` v-model, which you can then manipulate to change the tab.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      currentTab: 0,
      tabs: [{
          title: 'First'
        },
        {
          title: 'Second'
        },
        {
          title: 'Disabled',
          disabled: true
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.18.1/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.18.1/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div id="app" class="p-3">
  <b-dropdown :text="tabs[currentTab].title">
    <b-dropdown-item v-for="({ title, disabled }, index) in tabs" @click="currentTab = index" :disabled="disabled">
      {{ title }}
    </b-dropdown-item>
  </b-dropdown>
  <hr />
  <b-tabs v-model="currentTab" nav-class="d-none">
    <b-tab>I'm the first tab</b-tab>
    <b-tab>I'm the second tab</b-tab>
    <b-tab disabled>I'm a disabled tab!</b-tab>
  </b-tabs>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was trying to achieve, I just had to bind key to index for it to work. Thanks!